# Maxwell's eq-meaning of del's cross and dot product?

Tags: differentiation, notation, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

In maxwell's eq there is del whose cross and dot products exist.

So what is del in cross vs dot product.

What's the difference when it's just a partial differential operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't real cross/dot products, it is a notational trick.

$\nabla × $ is called the curl.

$\nabla \cdot$ is called the divergence.

$\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = \frac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial x} \hat i + \frac{\partial F_{y}}{\partial y} \hat j + \frac{\partial F_{z}}{\partial z} \hat k$

$\nabla × \vec{F} = (\frac{\partial F_{z}}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_{y}}{\partial z})\hat i +(\frac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_{z}}{\partial x})\hat j +(\frac{\partial F_{y}}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial y})\hat k $

Curl and divergences computation is the same as a cross product or dot product, but instead  multiplying the vectors, you differentiate the component.

Comment: So how is it different is what i asked ofc it's a notation but that's not my question

Comment: Without notation what's the expanded form in partial differential operators.

Comment: Look up the definitions of curl and divergence, that will give more than any answer here could.  instead of actually computing a cross product or dot product, where you would multiply the "vectors", you apply the differential operator

Comment: How is this tied to vectors

Comment: Briefly: The curl is a measure of the rotation of a field at a point. And the divergence is a measure of how much the vector field flows out of a point. For the intuition behind the curl and divergence, look up "divergence theorem" or "stokes theorem"

Comment: Can u write the formula of the expanded form of del with both cross and dot product. As that was what i wanted to know

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus if you want to learn about the curl and divergence, it's best to learn about these topics in video, to understand the intuition, without just remembering the formula.

Comment: Look up Khan academy dot product and cross product. If you know the computation, you should be able to get the expanded formula. I cannot remember the mathjax code for matrices so I cannot help you.

Comment: Matrices lol ... nah it's much simpler

Comment: It's simpler putting  in matrix form, hence why there's specific notation. But if you want the mess that is the expanded curl, read my edit. Or use Google.

Answer (score 3):

You're used to the definitions$$U\cdot V=U_iV_i,\,(U\times V)_i:=\epsilon_{ijk}U_jV_k.$$(I've used [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) without worrying about index heights.) Similarly,$$\nabla\cdot V=\partial_iV_i,\,(\nabla\times V)_i:=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jV_k.$$Since derivatives don't commute with functions, the consequences are slightly more complicated than for "normal" vectors. For example, in$$\nabla\times(U\times V)=U(\nabla\cdot V)-V(\nabla\cdot U)+\color{red}{(V\cdot\nabla)U-(U\cdot\nabla)V},$$the red terms have no "vanilla" analog. On the other hand, derivatives commute with each other, so e.g. $\nabla\cdot\nabla\times V=0$.

Comment: In terms of differenetial operators what would del cross vs dot be like?

Comment: @Minikute $\nabla\times$ needs to take a vector, which $\nabla\cdot$ can't return. But a third kind of del, the _grad_ of a scalar, $(\nabla\phi)_i:=\partial_i\phi$, is a vector you can pass to curl, viz. $\nabla\times\nabla\phi=0$ (again, this is what you'd expect, because the derivatives commute). Edit: I just noticed your "vs", but I'll leave what I already wrote. Could you clarified what you meant by curl _vs_ div?

Comment: i don't know vector calculus

Comment: I want the formula in partial different form, this the expanded version of that kinky notation

Comment: I've given you that. For example, $(\nabla\times V)_1=\partial_2V_3-\partial_3V_2$.

Comment: What is this notation meaning $$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jV_k.$$ , i am new to this notation and cant be expected to gey it

Comment: [Ah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).

Comment: $$(\nabla\times V)_i:=$$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jV_k.$$ why V i not V in general, can u write the whole formula minus the notation part

Comment: I understood thanks for the link i will read the notation as well einsteinian